# Is it possible to share one view between two models in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to share one view between two models? I have a panel with many identical components. Each of them has three numberField controls (new value, current and past), its own controller and viewmodel. But I also have a parent model. Can I use standard extjs tools to bind two models (parent and child) with different property names to one control?

```js
// view pseudocode

{
    xtype: 'panel',
    
    controller: 'parentController',
    viewModel:{
        id: 'parent',
        type: 'parent'
    },
    
    items:[{
        xtype: 'panel',
        
        controller: 'childController',
        viewModel:{
            id: 'child_1',
            type: 'child'
        },
        
        items:[{
            xtype: 'numberfield', 
            minValue: 0,
            bind: '{child_1}',
        },{
            xtype: 'numberfield', 
            minValue: 0,
            bind: '{child_2}',
        }]
    }]
}

// parent viewModel pseudocode

{
    data: {
        child_1_1: 0,
        child_1_2: 0
    }
}

// child viewModel pseudocode

{
    data: {
        child_1: 0,
        child_2: 0
    }
}

// need child_1_1 <-> child_1 and child_1_2 <-> child_2
```

I want something similar to this. I would like to be able to both assign and read both models and get the same values, as well as declaratively bind methods to value change events.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you need, but child components can use the parent view model, see [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html#application_architecture-_-view_models_data_binding_-_binding_and_child_components). If you can create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your issue you will get help more likely.